# Windows Installed apps transfer to ubuntu

Tags: backup, reinstall

I had backed up all my apps and software to a hard disk while switching from windows to ubuntu. I'm a beginner and I have no idea how to transfer the backup to the new operating system and reinstall all my applications from the backup drive.

Answer (score 1):

Windows and linux are different operating systems. While you can restore your data from the backup and use it on Ubuntu (which is one of many linux distributions), you can not restore your applications on Ubuntu. You will have to find equivalent applications to use.

Comment: In that case , is there a possibility to at least import app data from the backup. Some apps that I had backed up are available on linux too. Like transferring bookmarks of a  browser

Comment: @ShashankArunkumar Yes, bookmarks of browsers can easily be imported, as can Contact data  from e-mail applications and such things. In firefox e.g. you go to bookmarks --> manage bookmarks import. However, you will have to ask new questions for specific applications as this this question would get too broad.

Comment: I see, got it! Thanks a lot for the info!!